# Tricky sequence of random variables converges to $0$ with decreasing expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I am studying for an exam and here is a sample question that I am unable to solve. I would appreciate your help in helping me prepare.

---

Let $\{X_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $E(|X_{n}|) \leq 2^{-n}$  for each index $n$. Show $X_{i} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$.

---

So from the expectation bound, we have it getting smaller and smaller for each new variable in the sequence. I need to show the sequence converges almost surely, which, by what's on Wikipedia means I need to show that, $P(\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n} = 0) = 1$. I'm not so sure how to relate the expectations to do this though.

I am also aware of chebyshev and other inequalities but I am still struggling to solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

$E\sum X_n^{2} =\sum EX_n^{2} <\infty$ and this implies $\sum X_n^{2} <\infty$ almost surely. In particular, the general term $X_n^{2} \to 0$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Borel Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) lemma. In particular, in order to show that $X_i\to 0$ a.s., we show that for every $\varepsilon>0$, it is the case that $P(|X_n|>\varepsilon \quad \text{i.o})=0$ where i.o means "infinitely often". To this end note by [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)
$$
\sum_n P(|X_n|>\varepsilon)\leq \sum_n \varepsilon ^{-1}E|X_n|\le
\sum_n \varepsilon ^{-1}2^{-n}<\infty
$$
whence $P(|X_n|>\varepsilon \quad \text{i.o})=0$ as desired.